# Unicode Font Color in Android TextView?

Tags: android-layout, fonts, textview

I am trying to insert Unicode characters  into a TextView. In particular, I want to include a check mark and an "X". I found two Unicode characters to do this, namely \u2714 and \u2716. These show up as shown below. These are Ok I guess but I'm not crazy about the colors. Ideally, the check mark would be green and the cross red. Or at least both the same color. TextView.setTextColor doesn't help.

My guess is that these colors are baked into the font (typeface). I guess I could download a boatload of TrueType fonts and try them one-by-one, but that seems like cruel and unusual punishment.

**Does anybody know a way to change the colors? (or otherwise do what I want)**
  I suppose I could re-architect the app to use images but that would  entail unacceptably major re-structuring.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no one responded, so I'm posting this answer to capture what I *think* I learned. From my reading, it appears that color in TrueType fonts is a non-standard, vendor-specific extension to the TrueType specification, which was added to accommodate emoticons. So I guess I'm out of luck. Fortunately, It works fine on my Samsung if I can tolerate the colors.